# Laminar flow in pipe causing temperature in bath

Tags: thermodynamics, flow

I'm not really familiar with fluid mechanics, and I haven't studied Physics in a while, so if you point me to relevant material I would be super grateful.

Essentially, the problem I'm trying to solve involves a pipe in a small water bath that has fluid flow. Assuming that the temperature is constant within the pipe, what is the temperature dynamics of the water bath? Surely it is dependent on the velocity of the flow within the pipe? Problems that I have seen look at the temperature change within the length of the pipe, assuming the temperature of the bath is constant. I would like to do the opposite.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate, the amount of heat transferred from the fluid to the bath?

Comment: Are you looking at how temperature of bath changes with time from some initial temperature to the temperature of the liquid flowing in from the pipe?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I'd like to find how the temperature of the water bath changes in time and with respect to the velocity of the fluid in the pipe.